# How to choose tenses in story telling?

Tags: grammar

When someone asks me to describe a character from a story or explain the story briefly, should I use "**past tense**" or "**present tense**"

Below is the story about the character of the novel "Devi Chaudhurani" (written by Bankimchandra Chattopadhyay) from which I was asked a question in the exam: Here is the link that expalins the novel and the character briefly [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devi_Chaudhurani)

- Prafulla is married but is shunned by her wealthy father-in-law, Haraballabh, because of a spat between him and her father on the day of her wedding. By custom prevalent at that time, a girl, once married, could not be divorced or remarried. Heartbroken at the fate of his only child, her father died after a few years, leaving the family in penury.
- Prafulla takes the drastic step to flee in the middle of the night to find the house of her in-laws whom she has never known, without any money, with knowledge of only the name of the village and name of her father-in-law.

Here is the question that was asked in the exam "**Who is Prafulla? Describe her character briefly."** Should I answer in past tense or present tense in the answer?

- Prafulla **is** the main character of the novel Devi Chaudhurani. She **lives/lived** in a small village of Bengal. She **is** idolized in the novel as an Inspiration to women in Bengal that time. Prafulla **is/was** shunned by Haraballabh, Her father-in-law. This **made/makes** her father feel heart broken and depressed which **leads/led** him to death. This **made/makes** Prafulla more stronger than ever. By the character of Prafulla the author **described/describes** a hard and successful life of a woman.

I think both tenses are correct but not sure. Could you please explain? Can I use both tenses?

Comment: Sometimes certain examinations will include the use of certain verb tenses (such as the present) in their formatting guidelines. Is there any indication that a certain tense is required? From my experience, descriptions of the events in a book required the present tense.

Comment: Since the question is **Who is Prafulla**, the implication is that you should stick to the present tense. Had it been **Who was Prafulla**, the past would have been indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Narrative can be very complicated in its mix of tenses. But when speaking *about* a story that has been told by another person, such as describing the characters or summarizing the plot as it unfolds, it is conventional to use the present tense.