# Tense when recounting and analysing a literary text

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, present-tense

Should I write the substance of a poem In past tense or in present tense?

Here are a few lines of the poem owl:

Downhill I came, hungry, and yet not starved;

Cold, yet had heat within me that was proof

Against the North wind; tired, yet so that rest

Had seemed the sweetest thing under a roof.

Here's the link Vintage Poetry: [click](http://www.diypoets.com/vintage-poetry-the-owl-by-edward-thomas-discourse-by-frank-mcmahon/)

Here's the substance written by me: Should I use past tense or Present tense?

- The poet comes/came down a hill. He **is/was** hungry, tired and feeling cold. But he **is/was** not really starving. He **could/can** still relish a shelter under a roof, and **have/had** sufficient warmth within him to resist the cold wind. He **gets/got** food, fire and rest in an inn. He **is/was** protected from the darkness and cold that prevailed outside the inn. But he **cannot/could not** avoid hearing the sad note of an owl coming distinctly from a hill. The cry of the owl **seems/seemed** to remind him of those soldiers and poor people who **have/had** not been able to get food and shelter. So, although he **gets/got** food and rest, he **cannot/could not** enjoy himself.

I think past and present both tenses can be used but present tense is better. What do you think?

One more question, should I use **past tense** or **present** in answer to the following question?

- Question: Describe the feelings of the poet on hearing the cry of the owl.
- Answer:- The owl's cry **was/is** sad and piercing. It **makes/made** the poet ponder over the plight of the homeless poor and the soldiers fighting at the front. They **have/had** to starve and spend the cold winter nights in the open, under the sky. The poet **feels/felt** sad for the misery of those people. The owl's cry **picks/picked** his conscience. He **cannot/could not** enjoy his food and rest?

The question is in my text book with the above answer that is written in past tense. But I think present tense can also be used. What do you think? Which tense would you prefer?

Can any teacher or anyone who knows the language well please answer this?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble distinguishing this question from your previous one, [How to choose tenses in story telling?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/179187/how-to-choose-tenses-in-story-telling) Please clarify how this question is different from your previous one. Please see [Can I ask a question for the second time?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/can-i-ask-a-question-for-the-second-time)

Comment: Hi, this question is a little different because in my text book the answer was written in past tense but I want to know if it is also correct to use Present  tense there.

Comment: Please [edit] your posts to make clarifications (don't use the comments for that). Try to make the distinction as clear as possible. Include a link to the previous question and explain why it's different. Please see [Can I ask a question for the second time?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4781/can-i-ask-a-question-for-the-second-time)

Answer (score 0):

In general, when referring to past events, use the past tense.

The poet is speaking of things that previously happened to him. It would be incorrect to reference them as if they were presently occurring.